Accessing header in handshakeinterceptor springboot websocket and react
I am making realtime chat application using websocket with springboot ,sockJS and stomp.
I want to display the "User left" or "User Joined" message in chat. For this I am sending header as 'username" : username while connecting.
const socketFactory = () => {
                    return new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/ws');
                };

                const client = Stomp.over(socketFactory);

                client.debug = function(str) {
                    console.log(str);
                };

                console.log('Connecting with usernamae:', username);    
                client.connect(
                    {
                      'username':username,
                      
                    },
                    () => {
                        if (mounted) {
                            console.log('WebSocket Connected');
                            setIsConnected(true);
                            setError('');
                            stompClientRef.current = client;

                            subscriptionRef.current = client.subscribe('/topic/main', (response) => {
                                try {
                                    const message = JSON.parse(response.body);
                                    setMessages((prev) => [...prev, message]);
                                } catch (err) {
                                    console.error('Error parsing message:', err);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    },

now this request is received by HandkshakeInterceptor, where I am trying to acess username header from request.
public class MyHandshakeInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
        // Retrieve the 'username' header
        String username = (String) request.getHeaders().getFirst("username");

        // Log the full headers for debugging
        System.out.println("Headers: " + request.getHeaders());

        // Add the username to session attributes if it is present
        if (username != null) {
            attributes.put("username", username);
            System.out.println("Username isn't null");
            System.out.println("username from interceptor: " + username);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Username is null");
        }

        return true; // Allow the handshake to proceed
    }

as you can see I am also printing the whole headers from request but, this header doesnot include the username I sent from frontend.
Headers: [host:"localhost:8080", connection:"Upgrade", pragma:"no-cache", cache-control:"no-cache", user-agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; en-us; SM-N900T Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30", upgrade:"websocket", origin:"http://localhost:3000", sec-websocket-version:"13", accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate, br, zstd", accept-language:"en-US,en;q=0.9", cookie:"Pycharm-369fb518=23a11f68-6a45-4169-a4fe-9192e647ba9a; Idea-4b25f8b1=8b8f8caf-69fb-4378-8d09-f2eb6981096e", sec-websocket-key:"QYXmmrTxFlzbzBPi8/PKoA==", sec-websocket-extensions:"permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits"]

Stuck in this for while, any leads are appreciated...

maybe this helps. you can define a channelInterceptor and act according to the command frame
https://github.com/roaraurora/zhihu/blob/master/src/main/java/com/zhihu/demo/websocket/InBoundChannelInterceptor.java

Solved,
I found out that we can only access http headers and not custom stomp headers in HandshakeInterceptor so, Basically HandshakeInterceptor was doing nothing and I removed it. Alternatively, I access my custom header in SessionConnect EventHandler.
@EventListener
    public void onConnection(SessionConnectEvent event) {
        System.out.println("On connection event is triggered");
        StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
        String username = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("username");
        String time = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("joineddate");

        if (username != null) {
            System.out.println("Username from header in onConnection event is: " + username);
            accessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", username); // Store in session attributes
            accessor.getSessionAttributes().put("joineddate",time);
            System.out.println(username + " is connected");

            User user = new User(username,time);
            userservices.saveUser(user);

            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.setContent(username + " joined the chat");
            msg.setDatetime(time);
            msg.setSender(username);
            msg.setType('J'); // 'J' for join
            messageservices.saveMessage(msg);

            template.convertAndSend("/topic/main", msg);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No username found in headers");
        }
    }

